# Is it possible to pass extra argument to perl or bash script when executing it via curl?

Tags: bash, perl, curl, command-line

Pretty sure this is general question and not just relating to perl or bash but whenever I'm curling some trusted bash/perl script from the Internet I just run it as:-

`curl -L https://somesite.com/somescript | bash`

which would run the script that's hosted in `https://somesite.com/somescript`. But is it possible to pass extra argument to that script like a filename or dirname?

From my understanding so far the plain texts from `https://somesite.com/somescript` is piped to bash which would execute each line of `somescript` as it gets streamed but I'm a little lost on how to pass argument to the script that's being run.

Comment: With Perl you can do: `curl -L … | perl - <arguments>`

Comment: Upvote for finding solution for perl. I didn't know that existed.

Comment: (Sorry, missed that you asked for both `perl` and `bash`. Restored tags.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `bash`

  ```sh
  curl -L https://somesite.com/somescript | bash -s arg1 arg2

  bash <( curl -L https://somesite.com/somescript ) arg1 arg2
  ```
- `perl`:

  ```sh
  curl -L https://somesite.com/somescript | perl - arg1 arg2

  perl <( curl -L https://somesite.com/somescript ) arg1 arg2
  ```

Comment: Excellent. This is much more general solution than the one @Biffen commented on. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression that `-` or was it `--` in bash indicated no more parsing of the argument and should take that as a literal string. I don't know where I read this but I can't seem to find the link to it.

Comment: `curl ... | bash -s arg1 arg2`

Comment: @shriek, `--` is often used to denote the end of arguments. `-` is often used to denote stdin or stdout where a file name is expected. `bash` is different: "An argument of `-` is equivalent to `--`."

Comment: @chepner, Thanks! I knew there was something like that, but I couldn't find it. (So blind.) Adding to answer.